# How to install remote software NOT on a domain?

Tags: group-policy, powershell, remote-access

I have a situation where some software (that I wrote) is going to be deployed on 60 laptops for an event.  The laptops are all running windows 7, but there is no domain controller, and they will all be connected to a 192.168.x.x network using wifi.

Is there any convenient way the software (consisting of an msi file) can be pushed out to all the laptops and installed?

I looked at WMIC, but I think that requires machines be joined to a domain, as does Group Policy.

The other alternative is Powershell, but I have literally 4 hours to do this and will have no time to figure out the right script.

It's not the end of the world if it has to be done manually (I can find volunteers) but it would be nicer if it could be automated somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you're out of luck in many ways. The automatic install conduits Microsoft provides are designed to work within a trust-framework, a trust-framework known as Active Directory. For everything else, explicit user-actions are required. Getting the MSI signed by a known signing-key will smooth things along.

Comment: I was afraid of that, but we will manage.  Thanks!